# HBITMAP memory leak

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi, hbitmap, gdi+

No matter how hard I looked and whatever I tried, I couldn't find why this code is leaking. Actually, I'm not sure about the leak but the number of GDI objects increases everytime I use this piece of code.

```
HBITMAP hBmp;
hBmp = CreateDIBitmap(dc, &stBmpIH, CBM_INIT, m_pBitmapData, m_pBitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS) ;

Bitmap  *pBMP = NULL;
HPALETTE hPal = NULL;
Color col = 0;

pBMP = Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(hBmp, hPal);

if (m_bFlip)
{
    pBMP->RotateFlip( Rotate90FlipXY );
    pBMP->GetHBITMAP(col,&hBmp);
    m_bFlip = FALSE;
}
else
{
    pBMP->RotateFlip( RotateNoneFlipX );
    pBMP->GetHBITMAP(col,&hBmp);
}

delete pBMP;
```

I've checked the GDI objects with a tool, and what I found is the HBITMAP hBmp is the one that is leaking. How should I remove it?

DeleteObject is NOT working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DeleteObject is NOT working.

Let's assume that it is actually in your code even though the snippet doesn't show it.  Then the next explanation is this statement:

```
 pBMP->GetHBITMAP(col,&hBmp);
```

Which overwrites the value for hBmp, preventing you from releasing it properly.  Fix:

```
 HBITMAP prev = hBmp;
 Status status = pBMP->GetHBITMAP(col,&hBmp);
 if (status == Ok) DeleteObject(prev);
```

You'll probably need to do some more work on the error handling code.

Comment: Thanks. It was GetHBITMAP which prevented the releasing.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`FromHBITMAP` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536291.aspx):

> You are responsible for deleting the GDI bitmap and the GDI palette.
>   However, you should not delete the GDI bitmap or the GDI palette until
>   after the GDI+ Bitmap object is deleted or goes out of scope.

Deleting the `Bitmap` object is not enough, you need to call `DeleteObject` on hBmp afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need a call to `DeleteObject`to match the call to `CreateDIBitmap`. How exactly is it now working?